# AWS cloudwatch insight query composition for the following log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Trying to compose an insight query which would extract the following fields.

apiname, endpoint, responseCode, status

from the log:
`"{\n \"apiName\": \"test_Authentication\",\n    \"endpoint\": \"https://test.cloud.com\",\n   \"responseCode\": 200,\n    \"status\": \"Healthy\",\n}`

As of now I am getting empty fields:

[image]

Comment: Does the log actually have \" in it and does the actual log line start with " or is that just you trying to show the string contained in the log?

Comment: it actually has \" in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the parse message in the query which gave the result I am looking for.

```
| parse @message '"apiName\":*,' as apiName
| parse @message '"endpoint\":*,' as endpoint
| parse @message '"responseCode\":*,' as responseCode
| parse @message '"status\":*,' as status
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```